# Android: shadow of Image in ImageView

Tags: android

I'm developing simple gallery application. There is HorizontalView with thumbnails. By clicking on the thumbnail, a new activity is opened.
Here is it's layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/expanded_image_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
/>
</FrameLayout>
```

So, the purpose of the ImageView is to stretch selected image proportionally to fit the whole screen.

My question is if there is a way to draw shadow for the image (not for the ImageView - I could use android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame", but the ImageView matches parent container)?
Images are set (by means of setImageResource) dinamically. They have different sizes.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean with shadow for the image (but not for the image view)?

Comment: ImageView is the container of the Image. Here is the screenshot that shows the ImageView with shadow (while Image itself doesn't have shadow): http://mywebsys.eu/Clipboard01.jpg

Comment: So you want a shadow dropping from the image. Do you want also the two gray panes above and below? (the shadow will be over the gray panes) Or only a floating image with a cast shadow over the gallery (no gray panes)?

Comment: Just a floating image with a cast shadow over the gallery (without panes).

Comment: Take a look to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the effect you want, you need to solve two problems:

1. A shadow should be drawn outside the image
2. Image should float over the gallery

For 1. use an ImageView and:

- Set shadow a 9-patch as the background. The 9-patch is transparent in the middle and has a thin shadow/border. ([see docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch))
- Set the regular image as the source image, for example with `setImageResource()`
- Use paddings, not margins, in the ImageView so that the source image does not overlay the shadow. The paddings size should be the same as the shadow/border.

For 2. you might use:

- a framelayout which contains the gallery and the imageView from 1.
- a new activity with a transparent window background (use the Transparent theme). This way though, the gallery below the image won't react to touches

For the second point, see this [video](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.de/2013/06/devbytes-custom-activity-animations.html).

**EDIT**: this answer complements my comments to the original answer. See in particular the [linked image](http://mywebsys.eu/Clipboard01.jpg).

Comment: Thank you very much, Gil. Since shadow 9-patch is set as background of ImageView widget, there is still problem concerned with adjustment of ImageView bounds. These gray panes above and below the image on screenshot show real bounds of ImageView widget (source image is 800 x 600px) and real position of shadow. I tried to set android:adjustViewBounds="true", but that worsens scaling of source image.

Comment: From the screenshot, the image is on top of a gray window, it could be a dialog or an dialog-looking activity. If you go for the activity solution, you can set the window background to translucent and then set a simple layout with the ImageView. In this way you avoid the gray areas of the dialog window. Check the code from the video linked above.

Comment: If you find the answer useful you can accept it so to help other people with the same question.

Comment: The answer is usefull, thanks a lot. Unfortunately I'm a newbie on stackoverflow and have no right to vote so far (have no reputation so far).

Comment: Ok no problem. There should be a "v" (tick) close to the number of votes, you should be able to click on that. When it turns green it means "answer accepted".

Comment: Yes, now I see it. I've clicked

Answer (score 0):

Shadow for image is two type
1-normal shadow.
2-drop shadow..

For both situations you have two solutions like
1-use 9-patch image for shadow set it to background to that image.
2-use gradient background to image...

Comment: What approach you used ?

Comment: From the very beginning I used 9-patch image approach (in fact the standard android image dialog_holo_light_frame was set as background). But I faced the following problem: ImageView was stretched to full screen, so the shadow was dropping from the container, not from image (here is screenshot: http://mywebsys.eu/Clipboard01.jpg). That was despite the fact that I set height and width of ImageView to "wrap_contetnt". The problem was solved by movin resource images from drawable to drawable-nodpi and removing  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item> from style for transparent activity.

Comment: Nice approach@korovin.

Answer (score 0):

**Just to to clarify**: From the very beginning I used 9-patch image approach (in fact the standard android image dialog_holo_light_frame was set as background). But I faced the following problem: ImageView was stretched by means of layout_width="match_parent" and android:layout_height="match_parent" (to stretch displayed image proportionally), so the shadow was dropping from the container, not from image itself.

The problem was solved by setting android:adjustViewBounds="true" for ImageView and then by dinamically changing for ImageView:

1. In ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

2. In ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"